# Messed up Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot

I had windows 10 and debian installed on my laptop, and I intended to replace debian with Ubuntu. I was careless and and selected the "erase disk and install ubuntu" option by mistake. Although I didn't hit go on the "write changes to the disc" window that pops after it. I don't understand if I have wiped out both my windows and debian or just made them inaccessible.
gparted shows:
sda1: size 512mb, used 1.02mb
sda2: size 488mb, used 17.66mb
sda3: size 930mb, no data for used
Wtf have I done and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you've wiped it, even though you didn't finish the process. DON'T write anything to that disk right now!

Boot from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and install `testdisk` and see if you can recover.

Go here for instructions... http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step <sub>[(Archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614020726/http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)</sub>